# ionic app white screen "Death"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an ionic application with `cordova-network-information` plugin added to it.

1. The app is working fine on browser (`ionic serve`), absolutely no
   issues with it.
2. On performing live reload (`ionic run android -l -c`) with console logs,      it's working fine as well. But sometimes , it's showing the issue as `Reference Error : No connection defined`, again on saving the file , it works fine, doesn't show any error.
3. After building .apk and deploying it to device, it shows a white blank screen on app launch itself and never proceeds into the app.

Tried building .ipa and checking it on Xcode. Xcode is showing `some error occured` and nothing else. No more information.

If someone has went through this issue and got a fix for it. Please help.

Comment: are you using mongodb?

Comment: I am using angular-local-storage.min.js file, to store data into localstorage in device

Comment: have you tried debugging it with chrome? it will help you alot to find out the issue

Comment: I tried debugging in chrome, you mean adding localhost url right. And in that case, there was no issue. The issue comes only after installing .apk. I get only white blank screen.